# Infinite Scroll Implementation Renders Data Twice

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm implementing an infinite scroll in Nuxt 2. When I scroll to the bottom of the page, my function is executing twice (two `GET` requests). It should be once. How to achieve this?

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div v-for="content in contents" :key="content.id">
     <div>{content.name}</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  // Minimal setup  
  import { throttle } from 'lodash'
  import axios from 'axios'
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      contents: []
    }
  },

  // Methods
methods: {
    handleScroll() {
    // Vanilla JS
    const pixelsFromWindowBottomToBottom = 0 + document.body.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset - window.innerHeight

    if (pixelsFromWindowBottomToBottom < 200) {
      this.getContents() // <-- Fires twice. Why?
    }
  },

  getContents() {
    this.loading = true // Got it. This is this issue
    axios.get('foo')
        .then(({ data }) =>  {

          this.contents = this.contents.concat(data) // array

        })
  }
},

  created() {
    if (process.browser) {
      document.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(this.handleScroll, 300))  
    }
  }
</script>
```

`this.getContents()` seems to fires/renders twice: I get duplicate data displayed on page. Have I placed the `document.addEventListener` in the correct place?

Update:

`this.loading = true` is causing it. When I update the `data()`, this triggered the double execution.

Comment: Have you tried switching the `< 200` to `== 200` and see what happens? Maybe when you're scrolling you actually hit 200px and 199px from the bottom and thus making it fire twice. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks. I did gave that a go but sadly, same issue.

Comment: Hmm... not sure if this will fix you're main issue, but doesnt the javascript bits need to be wrapped in a `<script></script>` tag? Something like this... `<template> html here </template>` then `<script> Imports and js here</script>` finally `<style> styles here </style>`.

Comment: You're right, I thought I could write less here. I've updated. And no, that's not the issue ;)

Comment: Also, your methods need to wrapped in a parent `methods() { custom methods here }` similar to the `created(){ ... }` Not meaning to pick at your style of syntax, just hoping it would fix your issue.

Comment: is there a change you bind `handleScroll` twice?

Comment: Hi. I've made an update to the cause of this issue: `this.loading = true`